# Why can the String.format("%02d:%02d.%02d") display 3 digits in Android?

Tags: java, android

The Code A which is from a sample project use `"%02d:%02d.%02d"` to format a string of time, it seems that it only display two digits for minutes.

Normally, it will display Result A.

Because it only display 2 digits with `"%02d:%02d.%02d"`, I think the App will crash if I run it in a long time , but it can display Result B, why?

**Code A**

```
fun fromCountToTimeByInterval(count: Int, interval:Int ) : String {
    val minutes = count * interval / 1000 / 60
    val seconds = count * interval / 1000 % 60
    val milliSeconds = (count * interval % 1000) / 10  
    return String.format("%02d:%02d.%02d", minutes, seconds, milliSeconds)  
}
```

**Result A**

```
50:23.02
```

**Result B**

```
235:14.13
```

Comment: Because 235 is too big to display in two digits. `%02d` means *at least* two digits.

Comment: The format doesn't truncate if the result overflow. `System.out.printf("%02d%n", 5000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JavaDoc of Java Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html),

> ```
>    %[flags][width]conversion
> ```

combined with the flag,

> Flags
>
> `'0'` The result will be zero-padded

the width,

> Width
>
> The width is the **minimum** number of characters to be written to the
> output. For the line separator conversion, width is not applicable; if
> it is provided, an exception will be thrown.

and the conversion explanation,

> If the `'0'` flag is given, then the locale-specific zero digits are inserted after the sign character, if any, and before the first non-zero digit, until the length of the string is equal to the requested field width.
>
> `'d'`     Formats the argument as a decimal integer. The
> localization algorithm is applied.
> If the `'0'` flag is given and the value is negative, then the zero
> padding will occur after the sign.

`%02d` means a decimal integer where its number of digits is less than two, it will be zero-padded. Otherwise, just print it because the given width `2` means the number of `minimum` characters to print including zeros, spaces, and digits.